# Python Subprocess cannot find module

Tags: python, subprocess, python-import, python-venv, python-packaging

Been stuck on this for a while and can't quite work it out.

## Setup

### Folder Structure

```
- Home
  - folder1
    + script1.py
    + script2.py
  - folder2
    + script3.py
```

### Scripts

#### Script1

```
import logging
logger=........

import os
cwd = os.getcwd()

import sys
print(sys.executable)

subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'folder1/script2.py'], cwd=cwd)
```

#### Script2

```
import logging

logger=........

try:
    from folder2 import script3
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception(f'Failed to open: {str(e)}')
```

#### Script3

```
import logging
logger=........

<<VariousFunctions>>
```

I'm within a virtual environment and use spyder.

## Issue

`script2` and `script3` run fine, the default working directory is the project home, Home.
However, I cannot get `script2` to find `script3` using a `subprocess`. I have ensured it is using the correct interpreter `sys.executable` and set the working directory to be the same too via `os.getcwd()`. I put these in the log and as far as I can see everything is set correctly but can't seem to import the module.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder2'
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: You need to add `__init__.py` files (it can be completely empty, 0 bytes), in each directory that yo want to be an importable package. So it seems to me like you need at least `folder2/__init__.py` file.

Comment: Ta, will give it a try. they're not setup to be packages, just generic scripts, does that matter?

Comment: @sinoroc - no joy

Comment: If your want to `import folder2` or `from folder2 import X`, then there has to be a `folder2/__init__.py` file.

Comment: @sinoroc depends on the version of python in use, you do not have to add ```__init__.py``` the module is not being properly imported and python module imports are not very intuitive

Comment: I tried adding an `__init__.py` but no difference. Not sure why it would work fine within `script2` but not `script1`

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see the full trace of a terminal session including commands used and the output (error messages and all). -- Right now I find it hard to follow what you are doing. -- Especially I do not understand how the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder2'` is not caught by your *try except*.

Comment: I'm just trying to run `script1` from spyder. The try except _is_ working, I'm reading the exception from the log

Comment: as a python convention, your imports should be at the beginning of the file. If not, the calls to the function that use the imported modules will be much slower. Edited my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
from parent_dir.folder import module
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#standard-modules) you are appending the current path to PYTHONPATH and you should then be able to access modules in the path. You can specify `sys.path.append("..")` depending on what directory you want to add to the PATH